# how can i rotate an image and keep rotated while the cursor is hovering?

Tags: html, css, rotation

It's an issue with the circular flag icon in the screenshot below. I want it to rotate 45 degrees clockwise and keep it rotated in + shape as long as the cursor is hovering on the image; then rotate back ccw when the cursor leaves the image.

[image]

This is the code I wrote so far. When hovering the image rotates 45' cw correctly but it goes back to X shape immediately.

```
#icon{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    width: 2.4em;
    height: 2.4em;
}

#icon:hover{
    -webkit-animation:cw 0.4s linear 1;
    -moz-animation:cw 0.4s linear 1;
    animation:cw 0.4s linear 1;
}

@-moz-keyframes cw { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes cw { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); } }
@keyframes cw { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform:rotate(45deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes ccw { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes ccw { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); } }
@keyframes ccw { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform:rotate(-45deg); } }
```

So how can I solve this problem? I think the `#icon` should be modified a bit because it might keep its original state even after rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `transition` instead of an `keyframes` animation:

```css
img {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

img:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` 
or use `animation:cw 0.4s linear 1 forwards;`